# Clicking "Back" only ends up not showing text (HTML, JS, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a form that you can answer with multiple slides instead of scrolling

Currently, when I click "Next" (In the JS, it calls `next()`) it transitions to the next slide, no problem

However, if I try to go back (Clicking "Back" calls `back()`), the title shows, but the description of the slide doesn't show. But the text reappears in the next slide if I click "Next"

Here's my code:

```js
    var qTitle = document.getElementById('questionTitle');
    var qDesc = document.getElementById('questionDescription');
    var qEntry = document.getElementById('answer');
    var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton')
    var backButton = document.getElementById('backButton')
    var entry = 1
    var questions = ["Slide 1 title", "Slide 2 title", "Slide 3 title"];
    var descriptions = ["Slide 1 content", "Slide 2 Description", "Slide 3 stuff"]
    var answerHTMLElements = ['', '<input type="checkbox">']
    var answers = []
    function next() {
      if (entry != questions.length) {
        qTitle.classList.add("fadeOut");
        qDesc.classList.add("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(function() {
          entry = entry + 1;
          qTitle.innerHTML = questions[entry - 1];
          qDesc.innerHTML = descriptions[entry - 1];
          backButton.classList.remove('disabled');
          console.log(entry)
           if (entry == questions.length) {
            nextButton.innerHTML = "Done"
          }
          qTitle.classList.remove("fadeOut");
          qTitle.classList.add("fadeIn")
          qDesc.classList.remove("fadeOut");
          qDesc.classList.add("fadeIn");
    }, 1000);
    }; };
    function back() {
      if (entry != 1) {
        qTitle.classList.add("fadeOut");
        qDesc.classList.add("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(function() {
          entry = entry - 1;
          qTitle.innerHTML = questions[entry - 1];
          qDesc.innerHTML = descriptions[entry-1];
          console.log()
          nextButton.innerHTML = "Next"
          nextButton.classList.remove('disabled');
          if (entry == 1) {
            backButton.classList.add('disabled')
          }
          qTitle.classList.remove("fadeOut");
          qTitle.classList.add("fadeIn");
      }, 1000);
    }; };
```

How can I make it so the "Back" button shows the description of the slide, as the title?
(BTW, no errors in Console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your CSS of HTML, but I believe you may need to add the following lines:

```
qDesc.classList.remove("fadeOut");
qDesc.classList.add("fadeIn");
```

Comment: Wow... What a big thing that I missed... Thanks!